# Does anyone know if RHP (assumed to be rotor horse power) is equivalent to SHP (shaft HP)?

Tags: helicopter

I was recently reading a NAVAER aircraft characteristics summary of the proposed XHCH-1 helicopter of 1951. In the engine section it gives the engine power in "Rhp" and later in a 1956 summary gives the value in Brake HP (Bhp). See https://www.alternatewars.com/SAC/XHCH-1_CS_-_1_November_1951.pdf

Does anyone know if there is a difference between RHP and BHP. I'm "assuming" (and I stress *assuming*) that RHP is 'rotor horse power' and equivalent to shaft horse power. I'm again "assuming" that the technical description simply changed over the last 70 or so years.

Any thoughts or suggestions from any learned person out there? Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is somewhat speculative, but I have strong grounds for the speculations, pls read through:

I've only ever seen bhp used as hp measured directly at engine output shaft, although by definition bhp can be measured at any location of the driveline:

[Wikipedia: brake horsepower](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horsepower#Brake_horsepower)

In the particular case in question, I strongly believe the reason for the use of the obscure "Rhp" is the unusual way the powertransfer is arranged in this contraption: there is/seems to be no mechanical connection between the actual engine and the rotor. The rotor is actuated pneumatically by jets at the tips of the rotor blades.

There would be no point in measuring the brake horsepower or [shaft horsepower](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horsepower#Shaft_horsepower) of the actual engine due to "weird" power delivery.

It is therefore most likely the hp is measured at rotor hub, but since the rotor in this case sort of "is the engine itself", to avoid confusion, Rhp is used to declare power. The declared Rhp probably is shaft horsepower. Kinda confusing though :)

Note: several sources list rhp (with some variation in caps) to mean "rated horsepower, which according to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rated%20horsepower) means *"the maximum power an airplane engine can develop without failure when operated continuously or for a specified long period under specified conditions"*. Even with this definition, I think in this case it refers to hp measured at rotor shaft, produced by the tip jets.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. I suspected the same and yes I should have been more clear, the McDonnell Model 86 XHCH employed pressure jet-tip rotor system similar to the XV-1 and later Model 120 V-1 :Jeep". Thanks again.

Comment: You do know the actual mechanism by which helicopters fly? They look so hideous that the earth repels them. Rotors are used for guidance and during landing to force the helo on the ground. 

Comment: Jet rotor powered by two Allison T56 turboshaft engines that drove a separate forward located compressor stage via a shaft. Compressor stage had bell-mouth inlet. Engine had separate inlet. Pressurised air from separate compressor was ducted to a rotor hub plenum and through rigid blades to tip-jet nozzles at blade ends. Not known if tip-jet burning was to be used, Model 82 (XV-1) did and Model 120 (V-1 Jeep) could. No anti-torque rotor required.

Comment: For more info/data on the later (1957) McDonnell Model 120 V1-Jeep see:https://docdro.id/Ncz0Roq

Answer (score 1):

Rotor Horsepower (RHP) is the only way to measure power in a tip-jet propelled rotor system. Power turbines are rated in shaft horsepower, while piston engines are traditionally rated in brake horsepower.

Different measurement methods simply get different names to distinguish how that power level was measured.

Comment: Can you point to some documentation to support your answer? I'm not doubting you, but a reference somewhere would turn a good answer into a great one.